# Argument Exception

Tags: c#, linq

Building a list from model in C# using Entity Framework.  I am using LINQ to try to match up the first 6 or 7 characters in a field.  In a language other than C# I would use a regex expression.. or in SQL a "Like" with wildcard symbols.  Below is the code I'm using, and I am getting an Argument exception.

```
List<InvoiceHeader> tempData = db.InvoiceHeader
  .Where(f => f.ivh_invoicenumber.Any(t => f.ivh_invoicenumber.StartsWith(temp))).ToList();
```

Comment: What is `temp`? What is `ivh_invoicenumber`? Can you post the full exception?

Comment: C# does have `Regex`, you know..

Comment: Yes, I know C# has Regex..  But this is searching through an array.

Comment: @Tyler InvoiceHeader is an ICollection<InvoiceHeader>.. Temp is the string that the where<> needs to find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `ivh_invoicenumber` and `temp` are of type string

```
var tempData = db.InvoiceHeader.Where(f => f.ivh_invoicenumber.StartsWith(temp)).ToList();
```

If `temp` is array of strings:

```
var tempData = db.InvoiceHeader
                 .Where(f => temp.Any(t => f.ivh_invoicenumber.StartsWith(t))).ToList();
```